# How can I ask a question about the timing of a meeting so that the audience understands that they do not have to accept it?

Tags: sentence-construction, formal-language

How can I ask a question about the timing of a meeting so that assumes there is a possibility to not accept it?

For example, I'm scheduled an appointment for Monday. Something has happened and it would be better if I postponed it to Tuesday but it is still possible on Monday.

Is that correct to say:

> "I had only a question regarding timing of our appointment and please feel free to answer; Is that also possible that we meet on Tuesday?"

Comment: [correction: I've scheduled a meeting]

Comment: When you ask someone for a favor, such as rescheduling an appointment, there is an implicit understanding that they are free not to fulfill your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual question is quite good. You should use a dummy subject "it" instead of "that".

> Is it also possible that we meet on Tuesday?

The preamble is confusing for me:

> I had only a question regarding timing of our appointment and please feel free to answer;

This uses the wrong tense, and there are other small errors, and I don't know what you mean by "feel free to answer".  Normally when you ask a question, the freedom to answer it is implied.  We sometimes say "feel free not to answer" to mean "you don't have to answer this question".

I would simplify:

> I have a question regarding the timing of the meeting.
>
> {at this point it is likely that the other person would speak, to say "what is the question?", or there may be some unspoken communication with the same meaning.)
>
> Is it also possible that we meet on Tuesday?
>
> {I would now explain the benefits of Tuesday} Something has come up and Tuesday would be better for me...

You see I am trying to emphasise that this is going to be a dialogue. You need to listen and respond and be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

> "I had only a question regarding timing of our appointment and please feel free to answer; Is that also possible that we meet on Tuesday?"

You don't need to say *"I had only a question regarding timing of our appointment"*, just ask away.

I agree with James K, this is quite good: *"Is [it] also possible that we meet on Tuesday?"* or *"Is [it] also possible to meet on Tuesday?"*

You could also say

> Just in case Monday does not work out, would Tuesday work equally well for everyone?

or

> Is there another day that works for everyone, just in case something comes up on Monday?

or

> If Monday does not work out, what other day can we all meet on?